# Puppet Error 500 on Server. Could not find terminus puppetdb for indirection facts

Tags: puppet

I am working with Puppet version 7.25.0, I have a puppet master running ubuntu 20.04 and a puppet agent running ubuntu 22.04. I am using a control repository with r10k.

I am receiving the following error when I run `puppet agent -t --no-noop`

```
Info: Using environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Could not find terminus puppetdb for indirection facts
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I have come across this error before and managed to resolve this by installing a newer version of JDK. I am now using JDK 17 but still facing the same issue.

If I run `service puppetdb status` I can see that it is disabled. I receive the following output:

```
puppetdb.service - puppetdb Service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/puppetdb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
```

This shows me the puppetdb is not enabled.
when I run `puppet resource service puppetdb_service_status ensure=running enable=true`
I receive:

```
Error: Systemd start for puppetdb_service_status failed!
journalctl log for puppetdb_service_status:
-- Logs begin at Tue 2023-07-25 19:39:20 BST, end at Wed 2023-08-09 11:21:35 BST. --
-- No entries --

Error: /Service[puppetdb_service_status]/ensure: change from 'stopped' to 'running' failed: Systemd start for puppetdb_service_status failed!
journalctl log for puppetdb_service_status:
-- Logs begin at Tue 2023-07-25 19:39:20 BST, end at Wed 2023-08-09 11:21:35 BST. --
-- No entries --

service { 'puppetdb_service_status':
  ensure   => 'stopped',
  enable   => 'false',
  provider => 'systemd',
```

I am unsure how to get puppetdb working/ running to resolve this error 500.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The service name is "puppetdb" (the output of your `service puppetdb status` command confirms this).  Why, then, are you trying to enable and start a service named "puppetdb_service_status"?